# In android How to set listview 0th position as static and the rest as dynamic?

Tags: android

In my project i have to set 0th position of listview as static and the rest as dynamic. but i am not able to get the functionality.How to make 0th position as static?

Comment: you need to put here and show what you did. so that while answering one can be focused and have a idea what you are doing

Comment: you can set headerView to your list

Answer (score 0):

You have to use arraylist to display in listview. So first you have to set arraylist(0) to anything u want and then add dynamic data in that arraylist. and then set that arraylist in your listview. Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

In your Adapter class, inside getView method

```
if(position==0){
    //set the static content for list item
}else{
   //set the dynamic content for list item
}
```